# should these html codes run the exact result?

Tags: html

```
  <ul>
    <a href="#introduction"><li>Link to Intro</li></a>
    <a href="#main"><li>Link to Main part</li></a>
    <a href="#media"><li>Link to Media</li></a>
  </ul>
```

why the code above doesn't work but the code below works as it is supposed to do (Links to the contents of the same web page)

```
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#introduction">Link to intro</a></li>
    <li><a href="#main">Link to Main part</a></li>
    <li><a href="#media">Link to Media</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Use http://validator.w3.org to check if your code is even *supposed* to show any particular behaviour…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example is invalid HTML:

- `ul` can only have `li`, `script` and `template` children. In your example `ul` has `a` children. Compare ["Permitted content"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul).
- `li` can only have `ol`,  `ul`, or  `menu` parent. In your example `li`s have `a` parents. Compare ["Permitted parents"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li).

What happens with invalid HTML is unspecified, and cannot be relied on.

**Never** write invalid HTML.

To check your HTML for validity, use the [W3Cs validation service](https://validator.w3.org) (it's free!).

Comment: I've got it. Thank you!